# Getting value from first textarea and print that in second text area

Tags: javascript, ajax

I get value from first textarea and print that in second text area but when I replace the value in first textarea it adds value on the end of second textarea, I want that it will overwrite that value in second textarea whenever I enter a new value in first text area

Comment: Please add the relevant JavaScript code to your question.

Comment: Sounds like you need to clear the 2nd text area at the time of updating the first one. I'd recommend using something in your HTML for the first text field like "onfocusin="functionToClear2ndTextfield();". You can read up on its usage here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can copy the value from one `textarea` to another `textarea`:

```
<textarea id="txt1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea id="txt2" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button onClick="copyValue()">Copy!</button>
```

and in `script`:

```
function copyValue() {
  var text = document.getElementById('txt1').value  
  document.getElementById('txt2').value = text
}
```

[Working DEMO](https://codepen.io/mDEVnfe/pen/mdyvyNq)